# when insert dateTime object from C# code to Sql Server database the syntax format is change

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

when insert dateTime object from C# code to Sql Server database the syntax format is change
in c# :
static DateTime newtime = DateTime.Now;
the output is:
11/10/2020 6:22:06 PM
but when insert it in database the field will be:
2020-11-10 10:31:00
may i know the reason?

Comment: Date and Time data types don't have a format; the format is determined by the presentation layer.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what's happening. The date doesn't have a format when it's in a C# DateTime object, or when it's stored in a SQL DateTime column. It only has a format when being shown to humans or typed in by humans . So whatever format you're seeing is a result of the software being used to fetch the date from the database and display it. It's not happening when the data is inserted.

Comment: Also, the change of time you're seeing is likely to be related to differences in timezones

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `Database` represents `DateTime` in `YYYY-MM-DD TT:TT:TT` format. But C# is using your current system format to represent it as string. Also actually this the debugger calling `toString` method on DateTime to show you the string format.

But the both represent the same point in time.